# Angular ng-bind-html writes HTML 2 times on Safari iOS7

Tags: angularjs, safari, ios7, ng-bind-html

I have a problem with my AngularJS webapp only with Safari iOS7 browser. My code looks like this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="currentPage.summary"></p>
```

And inside $scope.CurrentPage.summary I have loaded a HTML fragment like this:

```
$scope.CurrentPage.summary = '<strong>The bold or em texts</strong> appears 2 times only with Safari iOS7 browser';
```

Is this an Angular bug? Or I have made something wrong?

You can see this problem in action (production environment) here: http://riure.lopati.cat/#/1/es

All browsers renders the strong text ("Superioridad Vs Inferioridad") only 1 time except Safari iOS7.

Thanks.

Comment: I cant see the problem in the link you given in ur question.

Comment: Do you visited with iOS7 Safari browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an AngularJS bug that it was fixed with v1.2.4+

Bug reference at [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5192).

Comment: I had been fighting this same issue, and just tested 1.2.4 on ios6 and ios7 and confirm that it's fixed.  You should accept your own answer.